# Cookies not set when connected through ngrok

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, axios, session-cookies, ngrok

I'm trying to use session authentication for my django application. When I connect the frontend app to the locally running backend server using the localhost address, the browser sets the cookies sent in the **Set-Cookie** header ( includes session_id and csrf_token ) and the user is able to authenticate himself. However, when I use an ngrok URL that points to the same server, the browser doesn't set the session_id and csrf_token cookies and the user is **Forbidden** ( 403 http response ) from accessing the protected endpoints.

**Some more context**: I'm using axios on the frontend. And django with DRF on the backend. I'm trying to authenticate using DRF's SessionAuthentication

**Django settings file**:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' : [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

**Authenticating endpoint**:

```
class ProfileAPI(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated & UserorAdminAccessOnly]

    def get(self, request):
        user = getCorrespondingUser(request)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        serializer = EmergencyFundSerializer(profile)
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fix is to change the default SameSite cookie value sent by django, by adding this to the settings file:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = None
```

For django versions that don't recognise these settings, install django-rest-swagger and try again.